# BAD ACCESS error while setting property using unit test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I am in the process of writing unit tests for my project. Following is the unit test:

```
-(void)testRecordMapControl
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *tempMap = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *testDict = [mAutomate_MapView recordMapControl:1 :0 :1 :[ @"-1" stringByAppendingFormat:SEPARATOR@"-2"] :tempMap :MAPVIEW];
   // STAssertNotNil(testDict, @"not null");
}
```

And following is the method being tested:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *) recordMapControl:(int)globalIndex:(int) mapCntlIndex :(int) controlIdIndex :(NSString *) viewIndexInList :(id) control :(NSString *)controlType{

    MKPinAnnotationView *mapView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)control;
    mAutomate_ViewBean *mapBean = [[mAutomate_ViewBean alloc] init];


    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [mapBean proxyForJsonCreation];
    [tempDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mapView animatesDrop]] ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mapView animatesDrop]]:@"null" forKey:ANIMATESDROP];
    [tempDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mapView pinColor]] ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mapView pinColor]]:@"null" forKey:PINCOLOR];

    return tempDict;


}
```

I am getting the BAD ACCESS error on the execution of the following line:

```
[tempDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mapView animatesDrop]] ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mapView animatesDrop]]:@"null" forKey:ANIMATESDROP];
```

Please can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Is animatedDrop returning a double? It looks like it's returning a bool...

```
[tempDict setValue:([mapView animatesDrop] ? @"1" : @"null") forKey:ANIMATESDROP];
```

Comment: %d is the integer (decimal) format specifier and BOOL is a typedef to integer in Cocoa. This won't be the problem.

Comment: it returns a BOOL. The thing is that this method does not present any problem when it is normally called. The problem has arisen when I have called it from an unit test.

Comment: turns out I'm getting a BAD ACCESS even after commenting the two lines after the declaration of tempDict. It happens when the control goes back to the test.

Comment: Check what `tempDict` actually is then, it may not be what it seems... `NSLog(@"%@", tempDict);`